# Warning error with TruncHTML

Tags: html, codeigniter

I’m getting this error with TruncHTML:
Warning: Wrong value for parameter 4 in call to preg_match_all() in /public_html/ee/plugins/pi.trunchtml.php on line 63
Using PHP 4.3.2.
I’ve contacted the developer but he hasn’t come back with anything…
Anyone seen this before?

```
      if (preg_match_all('&[0-9a-z]{2,8};|&#[0-9]{1,7};|&#x;[0-9a-f]{1,6};/i', $line_matchings[2], $entities, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE|PREG_PATTERN_ORDER))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no PHP version older than 4.3.2.2 where it works.
There is a bug report on PHP.net for 4.3.2 about this function, though.

You can try this,I am not sure

Open pi.trunchtml.php in a text editor.
Find PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE in line 63.
Replace it with

> PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE|PREG_PATTERN_ORDER

Comment: In which world you are living..its time to move to PHP 5.X.X

Comment: That flag was introduced in 4.3.0. That was in Dec. 2002 by the way, so not exactly recent

Comment: Great! That seemed to solve it.

Is PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE something new to the latest versions of PHP?

At any rate, it’s working well. Great plugin. Thanks for writing it.